# Explaining phrase お客様各位【きゃく.さま.かく.い】

Tags: usage, meaning

The expression `お客様各位` means *dear customer*. The first part, `お客様`, means *customer*, or *guest*. That is easy to understand for me. But the meaning and usage of second part, `～各位` is not very clear to me.

Comment: Disclosure: I don't know Japanese. I just stumble upon the article with the following title : 「お客様各位」という言葉は正しいのか 「お客様各位」以外の表現 It is about the subtlety of using お客様各位 explained in Japanese. Here is the link https://docoic.com/37665

Comment: @WinMyoHtet I converted your answer to a comment, as we usually keep link-only contributions in the comments. If you would like to give a summary answering the question, please feel free to post a new answer in the answer section.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

*Literally*, 各位 is a respectful way to say "each" or "all". So "All customers" might be a more literal translation.

*Practically*, 各位 is often used as a suffix in formal headings to convey the meaning of "Dear ..." or "Attention all ...". These kinds of headings are often highly stylized and fixed, so don't let it concern you if the translation doesn't work on a literal level.